# Store encrypted data into transaction

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

Let`s say, we have a simple storage smart contract in solidity.
[Simple storage pattern](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13167/are-there-well-solved-and-simple-storage-patterns-for-solidity)

Can ethereum store an encrypted string, for instance, "hello world" into the storage? Can ethereum decipher this string "hello world" for specific list of allowed addresses?

Answer (score 1):

Ethereum can store whatever bytes you want, so you can certainly encrypt a string and store that. But everything on the blockchain is public, so there's no place to store a decryption key. Even if the decryption key is off-chain, if it's ever brought on-chain to do decryption there, then everyone can immediately see it.

So encryption is only relevant of decryption is done off-chain. For example, you could encrypt something with a recipient's public key, and **off-chain**, that recipient could use their private key to decrypt it.

Comment: the main idea, provide encryption and decryption into smart contract with zero knowledge proof concept. Without any centralized application.

Comment: I think directly user doesn't communicate with smart contract but through middle server. We can decrypt on server. How do you think ?